# Eliminate lines with an unconnected end

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have the following skeleton:

[image: Skeleton of Image]

From this image I'd like to eliminate lines that are not part of loops.

I imagine this as a process in which ends of lines are found (marked with red dots) and the lines are gobbled up until there's a point where they branch (marked with blue dots).

I haven't found an operation for this in OpenCV or Scikit-Image.

Is there a name for such a transform? Is there a way to implement it in Python that would work efficiently?

I've also uploaded the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMdxe.jpg) in case the above image doesn't load correctly.

Comment: Fix your broken image link, please.

Comment: @LevZakharov: I've tried multiple things (hard refreshes, incognito mode, separate web browser) and still see an image on my end. I don't think there's a broken link.

Comment: Strange things happen:) I get "i.stack.imgur.com redirected you too many times." error.

Comment: @LevZakharov: I've tried reuploading the image.

Comment: I can still see the image on this end, but I've also uploaded it [here](https://imgur.com/a/2H9UtNw), in case people are still having problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a good way to do this in Python using existing libraries (though I hope someone is able to point me one), nor the name of this.

So I've decided to call this the Fuse Transform, since the action of the algorithm is similar to burning the lines away like fuses until they split.

I've implemented the Fuse Transform below as a Cython function for efficiency.

The algorithm requires a single *O(N)* time in the size of the matrix to sweep to identify seed cells (those cells that are at the start of a fuse) and then *O(N)* time in the total length of the fuses to eliminate the lines in question.

## The Fuse Transform Algorithm

```
%%cython -a --cplus
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage.morphology as skm
import cython
from libcpp.queue cimport queue
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True) 
#Richard's Fuse Transform
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738867/752843
cpdef void FuseTransform(unsigned char [:, :] image):
    # set the variable extension types
    cdef int c, x, y, nx, ny, width, height, neighbours
    cdef queue[int] q

    # grab the image dimensions
    height = image.shape[0]
    width  = image.shape[1]

    cdef int dx[8]
    cdef int dy[8]

    #Offsets to neighbouring cells
    dx[:] = [-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1]
    dy[:] = [0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1]

    #Find seed cells: those with only one neighbour
    for y in range(1, height-1):
        for x in range(1, width-1):
            if image[y,x]==0: #Seed cells cannot be blank cells
                continue
            neighbours = 0
            for n in range(0,8):   #Looks at all neighbours
                nx = x+dx[n]
                ny = y+dy[n]
                if image[ny,nx]>0: #This neighbour has a value
                    neighbours += 1
            if neighbours==1:      #Was there only one neighbour?
                q.push(y*width+x)  #If so, this is a seed cell

    #Starting with the seed cells, gobble up the lines
    while not q.empty():
        c = q.front()
        q.pop()
        y = c//width         #Convert flat index into 2D x-y index
        x = c%width
        image[y,x] = 0       #Gobble up this part of the fuse
        neighbour  = -1      #No neighbours yet
        for n in range(0,8): #Look at all neighbours
            nx = x+dx[n]     #Find coordinates of neighbour cells
            ny = y+dy[n]
            #If the neighbour would be off the side of the matrix, ignore it
            if nx<0 or ny<0 or nx==width or ny==height:
                continue
            if image[ny,nx]>0:      #Is the neighbouring cell active?
                if neighbour!=-1:   #If we've already found an active neighbour
                    neighbour=-1    #Then pretend we found no neighbours
                    break           #And stop looking. This is the end of the fuse.
                else:               #Otherwise, make a note of the neighbour's index.
                    neighbour = ny*width+nx
        if neighbour!=-1:           #If there was only one neighbour
            q.push(neighbour)       #Continue burning the fuse

#Read in image
img         = cv2.imread('part.jpg')
ShowImage('Original',img,'bgr')

#Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Apply Otsu's method to eliminate pixels of intermediate colour
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Apply the Fuse Transform
skh_dilated = skelhuman.copy()
FuseTransform(skh_dilated)
```

## Input

[image: Skeleton]

## Result

[image: Fuse Transform]

Answer (score 2):

In the following algorithm first I normalize the image pixels to have values zeros and ones. Then I examine the 8-connected neighbors of a non-zero pixel by applying a 3x3 unnormalized box-filter. If we multiply (pixelwise) the filter output from the input image, we get all the non-zero pixels, this time, their values tell us how many 8-connected neighbors they have plus 1. So, here the center pixel counts itself as its neighbor.

Red is the center pixel. Yellow are its 8-connected neighborhood.

[image: 8-neighbors]

We should eliminate the result pixel values less than 3.

The code will make things clearer. It may not be very efficient. I didn't try to dig into [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738867/2571705)'s code. May be he's doing a similar thing efficiently.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('USqDW.png', 0)

# set max pixel value to 1
s = np.uint8(im > 0)

count = 0
i = 0
while count != np.sum(s):
    # non-zero pixel count
    count = np.sum(s)
    # examine 3x3 neighborhood of each pixel
    filt = cv2.boxFilter(s, -1, (3, 3), normalize=False)
    # if the center pixel of 3x3 neighborhood is zero, we are not interested in it
    s = s*filt
    # now we have pixels where the center pixel of 3x3 neighborhood is non-zero
    # if a pixels' 8-connectivity is less than 2 we can remove it
    # threshold is 3 here because the boxfilter also counted the center pixel
    s[s < 3] = 0
    # set max pixel value to 1
    s[s > 0] = 1
    i = i + 1
```

After pruning:

[image: prune]

Comment: Your pictures don't show up. While your solution will work, I wouldn't expect it to be efficient since, at each iteration, the entire matrix must be considered. In the limit of a Hilbert space filling curve, the fuse is of length _O(N)_ in the size of the matrix and each iteration of your algorithm takes _O(N)_ time, leading to _O(N²)_ total time. My solution works in _O(N)_ total time for all inputs.

Comment: @Richard I know it's mediocre in complexity and there are lots of ways to improve it, but I simply didn't want to. What appealed to me here was the simplicity of the code, so just thought of sharing it :)